# Compile NMAKE created make files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cmake, nmake

I am quite new to Jenkins and build, so my question can be silly.

I have installed Jenkins and successfully installed plugins under jenkins MSbuild, Nant and Clear Case plugin and its giving expected output.

Problem is I have my own makefiles created in NMAKE for each components and i want to compile it with cmake as it there is no other way to compile NMAKE under jenkins.

just not getting ways to do it, please tell me the plugin to be used to compile make files created using namke under jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Xshell plugin is the solution.

It runs all my NMAKE scripts on cmd and i get the expected output. thanks for prompt response slav.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know anything about `cmake`/`nmake`, but there is a **[cmake plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/cmakebuilder+Plugin)** for Jenkins, and **[this blog post](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/cmake-builder-plugin-reloaded/)** shows configuration and mentions `nmake`. Is that not enough?